# ZIP file created using Java showing empty when open with Windows Explorer

Tags: java, zip

The below code is used to zip normal text file. When I extract using WinRaR its showing the content properly, but when I open with Windows Explorer its empty, no file listed. I am using Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit) operating system. Any idea why its not listing in Windows explorer? Thanks in advance.

```
File file = new File("F:\\sample.txt");
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    String outFilename = "F:\\zipped_sample.zip";
    try {
      ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
      out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.toString()));
      int len;
      while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
        out.flush();
      }
      out.closeEntry();
      out.close();
      in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // log exception here
    }
```

Comment: This code should work as is, the Windows explorer should show that the zip contains "F:" entry and "sample.txt" entry inside it. Log the exception properly inside the `catch` to see whether this code completes normally on your computer.

Comment: You should close() in a finally block. Also, if this is Java 7, use the new zip filesystem, it will make your job much easier.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin The code completes normally, I don't see any error/exception. But when I try with right click->Extract All, error "Windows cannot complete the extraction. The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid" is shown. I dont know why it is failing only with windows explorer.

Comment: Open it in 7-Zip or other dedicated ZIP file software. Seems like Windows Explorer is unable to handle the entry named "F:", both when just listing the contents and especially hwen extracting them, because "F:" is not a valid file name on Windows.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin, yes you're correct, i just changed code to  out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName())); instead of out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.toString()));  Now Windows Explorer able to show the content.

Answer (score 5):

ZipEntry constructor takes name but you are providing it a path by doing file.toString(); Try:

```
New ZipEntry(file.getName());
```

This will pass the file name.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem zip file were not extracted and was shown as empty the problem was in the folder names in zip file. If folder name consist of `> or <` symbols i saw the failure . SO in the code `new ZipEntry(file.toString())` i try to clean up any folder names with those particular symbols